Type manipulation with optional function
Need help with type manipulation. I have this interface
interface IFormData<Inputs> {
    data: Inputs;
    transformData?: (data: Inputs) => <Result of data transformation>;
    getData?: (values: Inputs or "Result of data transformation") => {...}
}

Note that transformData may or may not be passed as a function, this is an optional parameter.
How to implement so that when passing the transformData function, we change the type in getData(values: ...)?
Function for the interface
function transformer<T>({
    getData,
    transformData,
    data
}: IFormData<T>) {
    if(getData) {
        if(transformData) {
            getData(transformData(data)) // something to do
        } else {
            getData(data) // something to do
        }
    }
}

Examples:

With transformData:
transformer({
    data: {
        first_name: "",
        last_name: "string",
        age: 34
    },
    transformData: (data) => {
        return {
            fullname: data.first_name + " " + data.last_name,
            age: data.age
        }
    },
    getData(values) {
        "values" must be {
            fullname: string; 
            age: number
        }
    }
})


Without transformData:
transformer({
    data: {
        first_name: "John",
        last_name: "Makeev",
        age: 34
    },
    getData(values) {
        "values" must be {
            first_name: string;
            last_name: string 
            age: number
        }
    }
})



Result is an interface which help me to do correct function type
Example link

Is transformer supposed to return something? If so, what? And what's {...} return type for getData? A [mre] would be nice here so we don't have to make stuff up and hope it's close enough to your use case

@jcalz nothing. Just need to get right types in transformer.getData (values) function

@jcalz. It's a mistake. Function returns nothing. And the question is not what the "transformer" ​​function returns. Added the link to the end of the article

@jcalz the code has been edited.

There's still no return type for getData other than in some external link but I'll just assume any if you don't mind and press forward. Does this playground link work the way you expect? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz Do you understand code or are you a grammar teacher?

Shall we be civil to each other and work toward getting your question answered? You can look at the code here and tell me if it does what you want or if it's missing something.

@jcalz sorry but this is a normal question without insult, because I am on the site for the first time and I see that we have been sorting out grammar issues for about an hour. If you read the question carefully, then everything is described in detail there, what problem needs to be solved

Maybe there is a language barrier? I believe I have solved your problem. But before I write an answer explaining it, I want you to verify whether or not that is true. If you look at the code in this link, it's a link to a web IDE, you can see what I've done. Is it what you want? If so, great! I'll write an answer. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz Yes, maybe we have a language barrier. I looked at the example you sent, it solved my problem, thank you

Great, I'll write up an answer soon.

In order for this to work, you need your IFormData type to be generic in both the type I of the data inputs, and the type R of the return type for transformData:
interface IFormData<I, R> {
    data: I;
    transformData?: (data: I) => R,
    getData?: (values: R) => any; 
}

Then your transformer function has to be similarly generic. You can give R a default type argument of I so that when TypeScript cannot infer R from the function inputs, it falls back to I.  That way a call that leaves out transformData will get this default and then getData will expect I as an input type, as desired:
function transformer<I, R = I>({
    getData,
    transformData,
    data
}: IFormData<I, R>): void;

Let's test it out. First, when we pass transformData:
transformer({
    data: {
        first_name: "",
        last_name: "string",
        age: 34
    },
    transformData: (data) => {
        return {
            fullname: data.first_name + " " + data.last_name,
            age: data.age
        }
    },
    getData(values) {
        /* (parameter) values: {
            fullname: string;
            age: number;
        } */

    }
})

Looks good. Here the data parameter of transformData is contextually typed to be the I type {first_name: string, last_name: string, age: number} from the type of the data property. And the values parameter of getData is contextually typed to be the R type {fullname: string, age: number} from the return type of transformData.
Then, calling without transformData:
transformer({
    data: {
        first_name: "John",
        last_name: "Makeev",
        age: 34
    },
    getData(values) {
        /* (parameter) values: {
            first_name: string;
            last_name: string;
            age: number;
        } */
    }
})

This also looks good. The type of the values parameter of getData has been contextually typed to be {first_name: string, last_name: string, age: number} from the default type argument for R, which is the same as I, which has been inferred from the type of the data property.
Playground link to code
